# Instruction conditional if to checked double records

Tags: php, mysql

I have this table: [image]

How I can write instruction `if`, which will check the records stored at the same time (in my table it is column `created_at`).
For example:

```
if(created_at for record where key(it's column)='stan' it is the same as created_at for key='stan_key' {
    return records where key='stan'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Several options for this.  Here's a version using `exists`:

```
select * 
from yourtable y1
where y1.key = 'stan' and exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable y2
    where y2.key = 'stan_key' and y1.created_at = y2.created_at)
```